# How do I move an element of an array one place up/down with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have this array

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

What is a good way to target an element (for example 'b') and switch it with the next element in line (in this case 'c') so the outcome becomes:

```
=> ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: `array[1..2] = array[1..2].rotate`

Answer (score 9):

```
array[1], array[2] = array[2], array[1]
array #=> ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
```

or

```
array[1, 2] = array.values_at(2, 1)
array #=> ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no build in function to do this. You can swap the values like so:

```
array = %w[a b c d]
array[1..2] = array[1..2].reverse
array #=> ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
```

You could add some helper methods to the core array class.

```
class Array
  def move_up(index)
    self[index, 2] = self[index, 2].reverse
    self
  end

  def move_down(index)
    move_up(index - 1)
  end
end
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that this solution mutates the original array. You could also opt for a version that creates a new array. For this version you can call [*#dup*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) (`result = dup`) than work with `result` instead of `self`.

**References:**

- [*Array#[]*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)
- [*Array#[]=*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)
- [*Array#reverse*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse)
- [*Object#dup*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)

Answer (score 2):

Try this for swapping

```
array[0],array[1] = array[1],array[0]
```

or in general

```
array[i],array[i+1] = array[i+1],array[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to target the elements by their indices, a combination of [`insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) and [`delete_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) would work:

```
array = %w[a b c d]
array.insert(2, array.delete_at(1))
array
#=> ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
```